# Open a whatsapp group using my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, whatsapp

Is there a way to open a group on whatsapp using my app?
I've tried to do some searches online and could find anything.
I found the activity name that creates a new group but could find how to pass the information to it, is it possible?

Comment: i don't think there are...

Comment: Try e-mailing support@whatsapp.com regarding this.